# Error to transform character variables to numeric if file.csv uses ";" instead of "," seperation. R

Tags: r, csv, character, numeric, coercion

I have two question, which I would really like to find answers to. I tried to find the solution at all the threads which are already covering the "NA Coercion" issue or how to transform factors to numerics. Unfortunatly they are not solving my problem.

Thank you in advance!

---

1. Why does R detect the values of the csv.file as factors, instead as numerics?
   Here is an example how the first line of the  csv.file does look:

> 8248,76;7736,37;7669,27;...;-

There are just  numbers seperated by ";" and two missing values indicated by "-".

This is how i loaded them into R:

```
gdp <- read.table("gdpcap2.csv", sep = ";")

str(gdp)

'data.frame':   19 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ V1 : Factor w/ 19 levels "1058,72","1742,08",..: 17 1 13 15 7 10 8 6 4 2 ...
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 19 levels "1012,51","1584,46",..: 17 1 10 14 7 11 8 2 5 3 ...
...
```

They loaded in just fine but instead of numerics they are detected as factors.
So if I would be able to load them in as "numeric" my second question "How to convert factors to numerics" would also be solved.

---

2. How I tried to convert characters into numerics:

`indx <- sapply(gdp, is.factor)
gdp[indx] <- lapply(gdp[indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

I get following Error after applying it:

```
There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
...
```

Which turned **all** values into "NA" due to coercion.

Now the thing that really puzzled me:

I did the exact same thing for another csv.file which was seperated by "," not ";" and it worked absoloutly fine. The file that worked well also had missing values indicated by "-"

This is how a line of that csv.file looked like:

> Angola,-,-,1.7,-,1.7,1.8,...

And here the R codes

```
CPIall <- read.csv("CPI csv.csv")

str(CPIchar)


'data.frame':   19 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ 1998: Factor w/ 58 levels "-","1.4","1.5",..: 16 14 25 44 8 38 1 9 21 17 ...
 $ 1999: Factor w/ 58 levels "-","1.5","1.6",..: 16 12 26 45 15 35 1 11 25 18 ...
...

indx <- sapply(CPIchar, is.factor)
CPIchar[indx] <- lapply(CPIchar[indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Using this csv.file, I also got the warning message, but it only changed the missing values"-" into "NA" which is totally fine. The real values were all succesfully converted to numerics.

---

It should also be mentioned that I used `"stringsAsFactors = FALSE"` which surely changed the values to characters. But I had the same issues when I tried to transform the characters to numerics. In my view the two csv.files only differ when it comes to their seperation (, and ;). Originally the first csv.file, which doesnt work, also contained country names but I removed them, just to make sure they are not the root of the devil...

I would be thankful for any help!

Comment: I would suggest that you fix your source data and get an export where a missing column value would appear as `;;` (i.e. two semicolons, with nothing in between them) rather than `;...;`.  If you do this, then missing values would just show up as `NA`, and you should be able to read in everything as numeric.

Comment: `read.csv2` uses the semi colon as separator and the comma as decimal point. And you can set argument `na.strings` to *a character vector of strings which are to be interpreted as NA values*, meaning you can have several `NA` strings. (The italics are from `help("read.csv2")`.)

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot comment, but I guess you only need to use dec="," when you load your data in order to get R to recognise the decimal parameter.

Comment: You are a hero, it worked that way! Thanks so much :)